# React server not being updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first day doing react. Whenever I change something inside the Greetings() function and hit Control and S the website does not get updated and it shows that message (Waiting for update signal) on console so I have to refresh the page on my own but...when I change some styling and hit Control and S it automatically updates. Is something wrong or its just the way it works?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with React itself but with your build process. What are you using to build/update the page?

Comment: Ensure react is installed properly. Also are u running react in development (npm run start)?

Comment: Have you added the `<Greetings />` tag somewhere in your JSX of the `<App />` or it's children? The app doesn't re-render if the component isn't a part of the the main VirtualDOM components